# Retrieving JSON files only from specific date

Tags: python, json, datetime, time

I'm creating multiple JSON files which are named by their timestamp:

```
# open file for writing, "w"
now = datetime.now()
timestr = now.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
res['Date'] = timestr
file = ujson.dumps(res)
f = open(timestr+".json","w")

# write json object to file
f.write(file)

# close file
f.close()
```

Generating files that look like this:

```
20220131-161407.json
```

I now want to read to a dataframe only files created in the last 90 minutes so I've generated the relevant timestamp:

```
d = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=1, minutes=30)
d.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
```

How do I read only JSON files with the relevant timestamp? I now use the following to read all files in dir:

```
json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(cwd) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]
dfs = [] # an empty list to store the data frames
for file in json_files:
    data = pd.read_json(file, lines=True) # read data frame from json file
    dfs.append(data) # append the data frame to the list

temp = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True) # concatenate all the data frames in the list.
```

and it takes a long time to load.

Comment: Why not parse the timestamp from the `pos_json` string and add another condition to the list comprehension besides `endswith('.json')` (namely that the parsed time is greater than `d`)?

Comment: I've tried to do just that but I'm missing something: `json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(cwd) if pos_json.endswith('.json') & pos_json> d ]` . getting an error unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'bool' and 'str'

Comment: The logical "and" operator is called `and` in Python, not `&`. And you did not parse the datetime from `pos_json` (you may get away with comparing the string representation, but then you need to format `d` to a string before comparing it).

Comment: Use `with` statement instead of explicit open/close, as its more pythonic

Comment: also techncially you dont need itmestamp in the file names. yo ucan do something like `os.listdir` and get last created/modified dates of each file, and then sort them or filter them by that date value.

Answer (score 0):

Based on suggestions by @mkrieger1, this solved it:

```
json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(cwd) if
                pos_json.endswith('.json') and
                    datetime.strptime(pos_json[0: 15], "%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") > d]
```

Comment: you can alternatively use `pos_json[:-5]`  so code a little bit clearer